# How can R call the right predict method?

Tags: r, runtime-error, predict

I am trying to run someone else's code and it fails only in my machine.

The problem occurs when I call the predict method of the varest object of the "vars" package.

The code:

```
favart <- VAR(favardatat, type = "both", season = 14 , lag.max = 7, ic = "FPE")
fcstt<- predict(favart, n.ahed = 1 , ci = 0.9)
```

it throws:

```
Error in grnn.test(...): unused arguments (n.ahed =1, ci = 0.9)
```

I'm importing these libraries, maybe some misinterpretation is happening. I have no prior experience in R.

Packages:

- dplyr
- factoextra
- glmnet
- elasticnet
- BigVAR
- vars
- factorcpt
- nets
- readcl
- ForecasCombinations
- ggplot2
- sandwich
- cointReg
- caret
- pls
- tseries
- factorstochvol
- BETS
- dygraphs
- xts
- fpp2

Comment: Can you please include your big list of packages as cut-and-pasted text rather than as a screenshot?

Comment: @BenBolker the code is in my work virtual machine, but I'll write down each package

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and it seems that the issue is from BETS package. it make some troubles at predict function. so, you have two options to procede:
(i) use the predict funciton calling the package, like this - stats::predict ()
(ii) use another package to call the series. i believe that you are from brazil as you are using the BETS package. I have heard a lot of problems with BETS and an alternative is the "rbcb" package.